# Android: Loading AMP Formatted HTML into a WebView

Tags: android, html, webview, amp-html

I'm retrieving Accelerated Mobile Pages (APM) formatted HTML form a webcall. I'm then trying to display that AMP in a WebView. So I'm setting up my WebView like this:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
String content = article.getContentAmp();
webView.loadData(content, "text/html; charset=utf-8", null);
```

It displays content without error, but it's not displaying correctly. It ignores for example amp-youtube elements and embeded tweets.

Is there something else I have to do with the WebView or the WebChromeClient to display AMP correctly?

EDIT:

The answer below works. But in my specific case, I was using the WebView inside a NestedScrollView. Which worked fine in Android 5.0+, but below that, the amp- elements would not load.

Taking the WebView out of the NestedScrollView solved the problem. It's parent is now a relative layout.

So if you're having the same problem, try simplifying your layout so that the WebView is not deeply nested. And definitely don't put your WebView inside a NestedScrollView.

Comment: The final comment on not placing the webview inside a NestedScrollView is definitely spot on. That having been said, it's entirely unhelpful when trying to use CoordinatorLayout + AppBarLayout + CollapsingToolbarLayout setup w/ webview beneath. Any tips there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot display elements such as embedded youtube videos, images, tweets etc without giving the WebView a base url. The solution was to use webview.loadDataWithBaseUrl instead on webView.loadData. You must pass it a valid url.

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    String content = article.getContentAmp();
    String baseUrl = extractUrlFromContent(content);
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(baseUrl, content, "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

Comment: I know this post is really old but I am having an issue with amp components in web view. For some reason the components do not respond to click events, for example I have amp-ads which should open in a browser when clicked but they do not respond to clicks. Any help is appreciated. @ninjachippie

Comment: What is 'article' here?